# "Wallpaper" vs "background"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In terms of electronic screens (computers, cell phones, PDAs, tablets) what would be more accurate to say: *wallpaper* or *background*?

Comment: It depends what your intentions are.  The 'wallpaper' is an image displayed in the background.  It you are pointing out that a context-sensitive menu may be opened by right-clicking on the background then the presence of a wallpaper image in the background is immaterial.  If you are pointing out that I found a great site with lots of wallpaper images to choose from, 'wallpaper' might be preferable. Bottom line:  wallpaper refers to the image, background refers to a concept in a multi-windowed environment.

Comment: @Jim: I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: This question should have been asked on Programmer's forum. It is due to the history of computer software and systems.

Comment: "Wallpaper" = "Background Image" (for those who prefer to avoid the architecture and interior design term)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Wallpaper* is a Windows-specific term. On a Mac it is called the *desktop background*. I believe Linux and many other platforms follow the same generic term (*background* or *desktop background*).

*Background image/desktop background* are more appropriate general-use terms.

Comment: You are right there. On Ubuntu it is called 'background/desktop background', even in Win7 it is called 'Desktop background', but still most people use 'wallpaper' term.

Comment: Also, in CSS it's referred to as background/background-image.

Comment: Aaaand it's also called background in Windows 10 now. Just forget the term wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what your intentions are. The '*wallpaper*' is an image displayed in the *background*.

If you are pointing out that a context-sensitive menu may be opened by right-clicking on the background then the presence of a wallpaper image in the background is immaterial.

If you are pointing out that I found a great site with lots of *wallpaper* images to choose from, '*wallpaper*' might be preferable.

Bottom line: *wallpaper* refers to the image, *background* refers to a concept in a multi-windowed environment.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more appropriate to use "background".  Windows declared that it was wallpaper a long time ago, but I hesitate to use that term.

It *is* a background (before anything else) and can be referred to as such.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the more apt term would be *background-image*, rather than background. Considering the two, the difference could be that **wallpaper** refers to the background-image of the **desktop**, the window with the lowest z-order in a multi-windowed environment, while a background-image refers to the background of any particular window.